# Use fast.com API with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, speed-test

I'm new to angular. I'm building a speedtest website as a side project and decided to use [fast.com API.](https://github.com/branchard/fast-speedtest-api)  In my component.ts I've included the following:

```
constructor() {
    const FastSpeedtest = require('fast-speedtest-api');

    const speedtest = new FastSpeedtest({
      token: 'myToken', // required
      verbose: false, // default: false
      timeout: 10000, // default: 5000
      https: true, // default: true
      urlCount: 5, // default: 5
      bufferSize: 8, // default: 8
      unit: FastSpeedtest.UNITS.Mbps, // default: Bps
      proxy: 'http://optional:auth@my-proxy:123', // default: undefined
    });

    speedtest
      .getSpeed()
      .then((s) => {
        console.log(`Speed: ${s} Mbps`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e.message);
      });
  }
```

But when I run `ng serve` I get the following error in angular:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/fast-speedtest-api/src/Api.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\sacre\Documents\GitHub\speedtest\node_modules\fast-speedtest-api\src'
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited**

See [Github issue - Angular Integration #4](https://github.com/branchard/fast-speedtest-api/issues/4#issuecomment-586629847)

> This is ment to be used with NodeJS. Since it uses NodeJS APIs it won't work in the browser as is.

Based on that it is not supported to run this api within the browser which is where angular runs.

Comment: `./node_modules/fast-speedtest-api/src/Api.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\sacre\Documents\GitHub\speedtest\node_modules\fast-speedtest-api\src'`

Comment: And yes I've installed the package

Comment: Are you sure this isn’t actually a node module..?

Comment: @CarlosDaniel - I found the answer although it is not the one you were looking for.

Comment: @Igor i ended up creating a server, here is the project: https://github.com/carlos-dubon/speedtest